# How to change an image on mouse over of another image

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, onmouseover

I am building a website for a friend/client's pizza shop. It's local and he wants to have the basic features and not much if any maintenance. Thus I am building it in static html and css.

The problem I have run into is that when I attempt to make his menu appear one section at a time by having the onmouseover event change the image's src tag it never actually changes.

The way I have it set up is a 3 by 3 grid of menu titles, each 200 by 67 pixels. On each of them I have the do onmouseover="displaymenu(~)" with ~ being a number 1 through 9 depending on the button. The function simply calls a switch and on each case changes the src of an image below the others that displays the appropriate section of the menu.

I have the function set up like this:

```
function displaymenu(x) {
    switch (x) {
    case 1:
        document.getElementById("menuimage").src = "images/AppetizersMenu.jpg";
        break;
    case 2:
        //same as 1 except a different src, same for 3-9.
```

The image I am attempting to change has the id menuimage. This code is placed in the `<head>` section of my document. I can't seem to get the thing working, and have searched for a solution. If javascript isn't the way to go, let me know and I'll do what you think is.

EDIT: I have tried the 3 oldest solutions and found no success. Could someone tell me if it is only my computer having these issues rather than a code problem?

Thanks a ton, -Elliot S

Comment: i guess you mean the _head_ section. Try first to quote your image url

Comment: my image is within a div, which is within one more div. I figure the best way to show you would be on a server since it's not PHP. Go to [bestpizzaschaumburg.com/menu.html] sorry for it still being a bit sloppy, but it's a WIP.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
document.getElementById("menuimage").setAttribute('src','images/AppetizersMenu.jpg;');
```

or

```
document.getElementById("menuimage").src='images/AppetizersMenu.jpg';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the value that you are assigning to the .src property so that it will be interpreted as a literal string:

```
document.getElementById("menuimage").src = "images/AppetizersMenu.jpg";
```

Comment: the image doesn't display properly on IE or chrome even with this. I had tried quotes in the past and it didn't work, so I was playing around hoping to get it working. Would local viewing produce different result's than if I upload it onto my server?

Comment: The Javascript looks fine to me now - are you sure that the path to the image is correct? Try manually adding an <img> tag into the html using "images/AppetizersMenu.jpg" as the src value, if you don't see an image then the path is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is going to make you smile too

Your Switch was not working!

```
function displaymenu(x) {
var x = parseInt(x); // MAGIC LINE
switch (x) {
case 1:
   $('#holder').hide();
    break;
case 2:
    //same as 1 except a different src, same for 3-9.
```

Comment: That didn't work either, I also uploaded it to my server and checked online without sucess. Maybe it's my image tag which goes`<img id="menuimage" src="images/SaladsMenu.jpg" />` It was left blank of a src tag before, but I figured that it might need one. still no luck.

Comment: is that img within a div? or any other type of container? Can you paste some more of your html code around this element?

Comment: my image is within a div, which is within one more div. I figure the best way to show you would be on a server since it's not PHP. Go to [http://bestpizzaschaumburg.com/menu.html] sorry for it still being a bit sloppy, but it's a WIP.

Comment: $('#holder div.content img').attr('src','./images/AppetizersMenu.jpg');

Comment: your switch was not functioning, i parse your x to an integer. updated my reply above.